# CurrentCulture is ignored in DateTime.TryParse() when the date string is missing the year

Tags: .net, datetime, culture

Using the following code:

```
var value = "12-1";
DateTime dateTime;
var canParse = DateTime.TryParse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out dateTime);
```

The returned DateTime is the 1st of December of the current year.
The current culture of my machine is `{en-AU}` and the date formats are set up for Australian formatted dates. When I hover over the `CurrentCulture` I can see that it is set to the `en-AU` culture.

I realise that the value is not a complete date but excel handles the same case. The TryParse method is returning a US formatted date when the date string is not fully specified.

Anything I can do?

Comment: Would `TryParseExact` be suffice? Not sure what's your question

Comment: @SriramSakthivel TryParseExact makes you specify available formats to use, we want the user to be able to enter any format that can be parsed as a date, but we want that date to come back using the current culture of the current machine

Comment: Interesting. I wrote the following code:
  
`DateTime value;  
Assert.IsTrue((DateTime.TryParse("1/12/13", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU"), DateTimeStyles.None, out value)));  
Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2013,12,1), value);  
  
Assert.IsTrue((DateTime.TryParse("1/12", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU"), DateTimeStyles.None, out value)));  
Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2013, 12, 1), value); // Fails - value is actually 12 Jan 2013`  
  
Seems like a Microsoft problem...